# Neo4j relationship creation gets stuck during import

Tags: neo4j

I am facing an issues with my local neo4j database. I am trying to insert around 100.000 nodes and 380.000 relationships using the official C# neo4j driver. Most of the time the data import takes around 23 seconds (which is fine for me). However, from time to time (~every 3 time!) the import gets stuck. This means that I send a request to create new Relations (via http, see Wireshark screenshot below) but I don’t get a response back from the database (after some time i run into a timeout at my application). This always happens when I try to insert new relationships. Creating new nodes seems to work fine. The strange thing is, that sometimes the import finishes successfully without getting stuck in ~23 seconds!

The query that gets stuck is the following:

```
string query = "UNWIND {relations} AS relation " +
              $"MATCH (source:label1), (target:label2) " +
              $"WHERE source.ID = relation.ID AND target.ID = relation.ID " +
              $"CREATE (source)-[:newRelation]->(target)";
return ExecuteQuery(client, query, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "relations", ParameterSerializer.ToDictionary(relationInfos) } });
```

This is the query to create new nodes which doesn't get stuck:

```
 string query = "UNWIND {nodes} AS node " +
               $"CREATE (n:label1) " +
                "SET n = node";
 return ExecuteQuery(client, query, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "nodes", ParameterSerializer.ToDictionary(elements) } });
```

I always process 1000 nodes and relationships at once. I fiddled around with different heap and pagecache sizes but I doesn't seem to have any effect on my problem. If you look at the second screenshot it looks like the memory size is sufficient anyways. I also tried using the Bolt protocol instead of http. The problem still persists.

Do you have any explanations what is causing this behavior? Or do you have some ideas what I can try to do in order to circumvent this problem?

Thank you very much for your help,
kind regards,

Daniel

**Additional Infos:**

- neo4j is running on a Window 10 VM with 4 CPU Cores assigned and 6GB of RAM
- neo4j desktop version: 3.2.10
- neo4j server version: 3.4.9 (community)
- neo4j C# driver version: 1.7.0
- Configuration:

  - dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=4G
  - dbms.memory.heap.max_size=4G
  - dbms.memory.pagecache.size=1G

This is how it looks like on the wire:
[image: Wireshark Screenshot]

This is the workload of the VM:
[image]

---

**UPDATE**

I have some News. After some changes in my code the database doesn't stuck anymore. It simply takes a little longer to process all the data.

However, what strange is, is that the first batch I insert (around 1000 Relationships) take much longer then the rest. The first time I execute the Relationship query it takes much longer then the following one (around three times as long).

Is there any explanation or some way to avoid that?

Comment: Does your DB have [indexes](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/) on `:label1(ID)` and `:label2(ID)`? Also, are any other operations being done on the DB at the same time?

Comment: Yes, I have indexes on both. My operations should be the only ones executed on the DB.

Comment: If you still have a question after your Update, create a new question with full details (including your new query).